# How to close a picture after displaying it?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I wrote JavaScript code that displays an image on click for my site. How do I add a way for it to close after users are done?

```js
function picture() {
  var a = document.getElementById('QR');
  a.innerHTML = "https://www.yoapoyord.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Elfactor3.jpg";
  a.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<img id="QR" src="https://www.yoapoyord.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Elfactor3.jpg" style="display:none;" />
<button onclick="picture()">Apoyar</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dmtakr3w/

Comment: add a button to change it to `display:none` ?

Answer (score 0):

To close that image after displaying it, you can remove the node by taking the parent element and invoking .removeChild(node); on the parent element.

```
function closePicture() {
  var a = document.getElementById('QR');
  var parent = a.parentNode;
  console.log(parent);
  parent.removeChild(a);
}
```

If you assign this function to a button you are able to close the image by clicking it:

```
<button onclick="closePicture()">Close</button>
```

You can also do a setTimeout() to automatically close the image after a certain amount of seconds or so:

// Removes the image after 5 seconds upon opening:

```
function picture() { 
  var a = document.getElementById('QR');
  a.innerHTML = "https://www.yoapoyord.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Elfactor3.jpg";
  a.style.display='block';

  setTimeout(function() {
    var a = document.getElementById('QR');
    a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Set timeout is great but since I'm displaying QR codes for an App that is IONIC based (Cordova) my users are forced to scan from one device unto another or a surface. Testing the onclick event to the QR tag is working out the best..  I am open for any suggestions that could help make this global as I would literally have to add this function to each post...

Answer (score 0):

As Sag1v said in the comments, just add an on click event to the QR code tag and switch the display back to none.

```js
function picture() {
  var a = document.getElementById('QR');
  a.innerHTML = "https://www.yoapoyord.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Elfactor3.jpg";
  a.style.display = 'block';
}

function closePicture() {
    var a = document.getElementById('QR');
    a.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<img id="QR" src="https://www.yoapoyord.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Elfactor3.jpg" style="display:none;" onclick="closePicture()" />
<button onclick="picture()">Apoyar</button>
```